# "No process is on the other end of the pipe" Write-Verbose Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, pipeline

I am trying to sort out an error on my boss' computer when he runs a PowerShell command (to build our software). He is the first developer running Windows 10. All others are still on Win 8.1.

The error looks like `Write-Verbose` is not working on Windows 10. But I find that hard to believe:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden 
  -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
  -Command "Import-Module 'X:\ReleaseRoot\CompanyName\Deployment\CompanyName.Build' 
  -DisableNameChecking -Force; Generate-SvDeployManifest  " -verbose
Write-Verbose : The Win32 internal error "No process is on the other end of
  the pipe" 0xE9 occurred while getting console output buffer information. 
  Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.
At X:\ReleaseRoot\CompanyName\Deployment\CompanyName.Build\Functions\Nuget\Restore-NugetPackages.ps1:23 char:9
  +       Write-Verbose "Restoring packages from $_"
  +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  +  Category Info         : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Write-Verbose], HostException
  +  FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteVerboseCommand
```

The PowerShell function that is failing is very simple:

```
function Restore-NugetPackages
{
  $packageConfigs = @("$RootFolder\Build\nuget\packages.config")

  $packageConfigs | ForEach {

    Write-Verbose "Restoring packages from $_"
    & $RootFolder\Build\nuget\nuget.exe restore $_ -PackagesDirectory "$RootFolder\Build\packages" | Write-Verbose

    # Output the versions of the nuget packages
    ([xml] ( Get-Content $_ )).packages.package | Select id, version
  }
}
```

This function works perfectly on Windows 8.1.

I'm stumped. Any clues?

Comment: Kind of off-topic but what is the point of doing verbose output in a non-interactive hidden window?

Comment: Because such output is captured in the log file.

Comment: Can he open up a PowerShell console, import the module and then run that function interactively?  Start first by making it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is he using the 32bit or 64bit version of powershell. There are some inconsistencies with the 32 bit. It seems like the verbose stream is not there.

Comment: He's running the 64-bit version of Windows PowerShell ISE. (Assuming that because it doesn't say x86 in the titlebar that it must be the 64-bit version.)